# Why play framework 2.3 is slower than previous play framework releases?

Tags: playframework

Why play framework 2.3 is slower than previous play framework releases?
I did migrations from 2.1 to 2.3 version. 
In 2.1 version compilation and deployment takes about 2 min.
But in 2.3 version it takes about 10 min. 
Why it is so? And my project works slower now.

Comment: Check the change log yourself

Comment: I doubt anyone could answer your question with only this information. How big is your app? What is making it take so much time: Compilation? Dependency resolution/download? Note that the first time you compile your upgraded app it will take a lot of time (in my experience) to download all the dependencies.

Comment: @Salem Yeah, compilation process take so must time. Now I deploy application using "dist" method - this helps me to reduce ram consumption and my application works faster. I have quite slow pc i3 processor with 2 gb ram.